# How to check if store is open or closed based on user different timezone and operation time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timezone

How to check if store is open or closed based on `opening time`, `closing time` and `timezone`. Currently I have the code which am using in server side to check if store is still open or closed but I have been trying to make the same function in javascript or jQuery with no luck.

```
function OperationHours($open, $close, $timezone = "GMT"){
    $status = 'closed';
    $nowTime = new DateTime("NOW", new DateTimeZone($timezone));    
    $openTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $open, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    $closeTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:iA', $close, new DateTimeZone($timezone));

    // check if the close time is before the opening time       
    if($closeTime <= $openTime){
        $closeTime->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
    }

    if ($nowTime > $openTime && $nowTime < $closeTime){
        $status = 'open';
    }
    return $status;
}
echo OperationHours("7:00AM", "10:30PM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur");
```

Comment: Is your code written in Javascript or Java?

Comment: @lthh89vt Javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) for this.

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
const isOpen = (openTime, closeTime, timezone) => {
  const now = moment().tz(timezone);
  const storeOpenTime = moment.tz(openTime, "h:mmA", timezone);
  const storeCloseTime = moment.tz(closeTime, "h:mmA", timezone);

  return now.isBetween(storeOpenTime, storeCloseTime);
}

console.log(isOpen("7:00AM", "10:30PM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"))
```

Comment: Moment Timezone has no data for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur

Comment: But it always show this error `Moment Timezone has no data for Asia/Kuala_Lumpur. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.moment-timezone.min.js:1:3312` and always returning `false` even when time has passed or still open

Comment: Okay, i think i used wrong js `moment-timezone.min.js` it should be this `moment-timezone-with-data.min.js`

Comment: if this solution works for you can you accept it as the correct answer?